# Reading from multiple lines from a txt file in a single iteration

Tags: c++, file

I am working at the moment with linked lists, and my nodes have 4 elements( where each of them is a variable type string). In a .txt file there are groups of text where each group has 4 lines, for example:

- This is the first line
- This is the second line
- This is the third line
- This is the fourth line
- '\n'
- This is the fifth line
- This is the sixth line
- This is the seventh line
- This is the eighth line

and so on and so on...
What I'm trying to achieve is reading the four lines in a single iteration and give them to a node, and let the program iterate until there is no more lines.

So if reading the example above our nodes will be left with;

Node1.string1 = This is the first line;

Node1.string2 = This is the second line;

Node1.string3 = This is the third line;

Node1.string4 = This is the fourth line;

While looking for a way to do this on internet, I found one way you can do this and tell the "ifstream reader" to do a '\n' before the next iteration, but I lost this page and cant seem to find it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show code?

Comment: I've tried using a for (string line; getline(reader, line); )
with istringstream; the issue with this is that I can read multiple things from a line separeted by a character. But this time the things that I will working with are too large to have multiple of them in a single line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough

```
while (getline(in, node.string1) && 
    getline(in, node.string2) && 
    getline(in, node.string3) && 
    getline(in, node.string4))
{
    ...
    string dummy;
    getline(in, dummy); // skip blank line
}
```

You can also use `in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>, '\n');` to skip the blank line, but reading into a dummy variable allows you to easily check if the blank line really is blank.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm always having a hard time when working with files and this is specifically what I needed.